# Meaning of the word mesmo?

Tags: gramática

How do you distinguish between the many uses of the word mesmo in a sentence?

I was able to come up with some rules but I don’t know if they are correct:

- An article word (o, os, a, as) used immediately before mesmo: meaning of mesmo is the “same” or “equal”
- Subject word used immediately before mesmo:  meaning of mesmo is “myself” or “itself”
- Used as first word of sentence, meaning is “even”
- All other uses the meaning of mesmo is “really”

Are my rules correct? Did I miss anything?

Comment: I suggest you write some sentences as context is always important. I could answer this as is but would have to work harder than you have. :)

Comment: Depending on context, "o mesmo" can translate as either "the same" or "the very".

Answer (score 3):

You get the gist of it very well. A few comments:

> An article word (o, os, a, as) used immediately before mesmo: meaning of mesmo is the “same” or “equal”

Yes, not only with articles, but also "*este*", "*aquele*", etc. ("this", "that"):
"*Li esse mesmo livro ontem.*" ("I've read this same book yesterday.")

> Subject word used immediately before mesmo: meaning of mesmo is “myself” or “itself”

Not always, the real purpose in this case is to give emphasis, so it could also mean, e.g., "certainly":
"*Ele mesmo que me bateu.*" ("He's for sure the guy who beat me up.")

> Used as first word of sentence, meaning is “even”

But one could change the order in the sentence:
"*Você tem que pagar, mesmo desempregado.*" ("You have to pay, even being unemployed.")

> All other uses the meaning of mesmo is “really”

There are at least another two possible meanings:

- to refer to something mentioned previously:
  "*Procurei o João, mas o mesmo não se encontrava.*" ("I looked for João, but he wasn't there.")
- especially in the expression "*mesmo assim*": "anyway", "regardless", "in spite of this":
  "*Ela estava ferida, mas terminou a corrida mesmo assim.*" ("She was injured, but finished the race anyway.")
  "*Mesmo ferida, terminou a corrida.*" ("Despite being injured she finished the race.")